# Find total of registered user in the last 7 days using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm storing my data in a schema like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Cst.png)

I wonder how i can create a query in mongoose to get count of created user in the last 7 days where I expect  my output to be like this

{
day1: 4,
day2: 4,
day3: 9,
day4: 12,
day5: 7,
day6: 0,
day7: 10
}

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I used mongo aggregate to group the data you need daily like this:

```js
const toDate = new Date("2022-04-08");

const fromDate = new Date("2022-04-01");

const data = await User.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: new Date(fromDate),
        $lte: new Date(toDate),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      day: {
        $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"
      },
      month: {
        $month: "$createdAt"
      },
      year: {
        $year: "$createdAt"
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        day: "$day",
        year: "$year",
        month: "$month",
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      day: "$_id.day",
      month: "$_id.month",
      year: "$_id.year",
      count: "$count",
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help. I think I should learn more about MongoDB aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

```
const usersCount = await User.countDocuments({
  created_at: { $lt: new Date('2022-04-08'), $gt: new Date('2022-04-01') }
});
```

This will give you count for users created in last seven days.  Dynamic date you can generate in your express backend.

Comment: the query generates total count of the data. What if I want to get the counted user data group by date?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite familiar with MongoDB. I just learned about it recently.

Comment: @EvanSamuel [mongoosejs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-countDocuments) countDocuments is also in mongoose. Yes this will generate total count for 7 days but you can edit the dates to request for each day instead.